# Is There An Automatic Precision Screwdriver For Small Works?

Tags: assembly, tools, automation

I need automatic tool to work with small electronical things but don't know of any good one. I am looking for something like this but of better quality and switch but push forward/reverse button:

[image]

If anyone uses automatic precision screwdriver and is satisified with it, can please recommend me something?

Thanks.

Comment: The brand "General"??? Silliest brand name ever? Google returns almost 5 *billion* hits for the word "general"...

Comment: @stevenvh: Practically guarantees you'll never find a review on it (which I'll bet is intentional)

Answer (score 3):

Dremel, well known for other rotary tools, has the [Dremel Driver™](http://www.dremeleurope.com/dremelocs-za/product/2721/345/dremel%C2%AE-driver%E2%84%A2/dremel%C2%AE-driver%E2%84%A2), which has a variable speed 0 to 300 rpm and is only 12.6cm long.

[image: Dremel Driver]

Answer (score 1):

How much quality are you looking for?  On a factory assembly line they'd use [something like this](http://www.eis-inc.com/suppliers/productdetail.asp?prod_nbr=64110-JER&Catalog_Area=Torque%20Drivers/Torque%20Wrenches&SupCoName=ASG-Jergens).  They are very nice to use.  Not battery operated though and $800 may be more than you want to spend for home use.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link replaced, please try again